# why kotlin activity xml doesn't have related files

Tags: android, kotlin

we've an icon in `layout.xml` files which will show the related files.

[image]

For Java Activity, when I click this icon, I'm able to go to the related Activity.

But Kotlin Activity's xml says that there are no related files.

[image]

whereas I do have a related Activity.

```
class SelectedAssets : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.-----selected_assets_activity)
    }   
}
```

Any settings do I need to do in order to get the related kotlin files/activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `tools:context="packagename.YourActivity"` to link it to the class file